# Sed to remove more than 2 words in single line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm asking your help, I want to remove words 'TAGS' , 'Owner' , 'QA'  from the txt file . in single sed command , example  `sed -e 's/\TAGS//g' test.txt` and add the email address example John@gmail.com to the end of the line example `postgres    vp-postgres None    default:postgres-13 True    stopped db.m6g.large    13.4    vpc-95525af1 John@gmail.com`

```
postgres    vp-postgres None    default:postgres-13 True    stopped db.m6g.large    13.4    vpc-95525af1
TAGS    Owner   John@gmail.com
TAGS        QA
TAGS    autostop    yes
```

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. I'm having a very hard time understanding the logic you want to apply and we are guessing at what `test.txt` looks like (unless that stuff you pasted at the end of your question is `test.txt`?). At any rate, sample data and desired results would probably answer all of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be first matching the line that starts with postgress.

Then pull the next line in the pattern space, and replace the leading TAGS or Owner or QA.

```
sed -E '/^postgres/{N;s/\n([[:blank:]]*(TAGS|Owner|QA))*//}' file test.txt
```

Output

```
postgres    vp-postgres None    default:postgres-13 True    stopped db.m6g.large    13.4    vpc-95525af1   John@gmail.com
TAGS        QA
TAGS    autostop    yes
```

---

If you only want that modified line as an output:

```
sed -En '/^postgres/{N;s/\n([[:blank:]]*(TAGS|Owner|QA))*//;p}' file
```

Output

```
postgres    vp-postgres None    default:postgres-13 True    stopped db.m6g.large    13.4    vpc-95525af1   John@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform multiple commands in a single invocation of `sed`:

```
sed -e s/TAGS//g -e s/Owner//g -e s/QA//g -e '/^postgres/s/$/ John@gmail.com/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\<(TAGS|Owner|QA)\>//g
        /^postgres    vp-postgres None    default:postgres-13 True    stopped db.m6g.large    13.4    vpc-95525af$/s/$/ John@gmail.com/' file
```

Us word boundaries and alternation to match words to be removed and match on a complete line to append the required text.